# Why i can't build Clp

Tags: julia, linear-programming, julia-jump, clp

i'm facing hard times building `Clp` package, it takes forever.
After adding the package i try to build it `Pkg>Build Clp`the only thing that i'm getting is this :
`` Building Clp → `~/.julia/packages/Clp/IBQzB/deps/build.log` ``
without any results, i'm using Julia 1.3.0-rc3.0

Comment: I was able to build it on -rc2.0: https://i.imgur.com/buEbSFG.png

Comment: can you give me the link to where i can download it cause i didn't find -rc2.0 on the official website

Comment: here are the downloads [for windows](https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/winnt/x64/1.3/julia-1.3.0-rc2-win64.exe) and [for linux](https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/linux/x64/1.3/julia-1.3.0-rc2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz). So far, 1.3.0 is a upcoming release. The current stable version is 1.2.0 and you might check that also.

Comment: what about MacOs?

Comment: [here](https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/mac/x64/1.3/julia-1.3.0-rc2-mac64.dmg)
You can adapt the URL for any Julia version.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `Clp.jl` doesn't support officialy Julia 1.3